# Where to dealloc local object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

In viewDidLoad I have the following added to the subview:

```
NSArray *pa = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Test", nil];
UISegmentedControl *gobtn = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:go];
```

Where would I dealloc this local object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can release it (don't dealloc directly!) after you use it somewhere else, such as `[myView addSubview:gobtn]`. Read the [Memory Management programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) for more information. Furthermore, if you're making a new app for iOS 5 you should consider using ARC, with which the compiler will do this for you.

Comment: It is autoreleased so you don't have to worry about it. If you used `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, or `retain`, then you would have to deal with it. PLEASE read the guide I linked, it will help you a lot.

Comment: Yes, I am going through it should help me understand the differences between all those. Thanks!

Comment: By convention (with the usual set of obscure exceptions) only the alloc method retains without doing an autorelease.  The [NSArray array...] methods are not themselves literal "alloc" operations (though they do implement alloc internally) so they perform an autorelease.  As a result, they do not require an explicit release by the user.

Comment: Yes, it's really an issue of ownership (this will be further emphasized when ARC use becomes commonplace). The point is that the `+array...` methods return an object which you don't own — you're free to use it within the scope, but if you want to hold onto it you have to retain it. `alloc` and the other methods, on the other hand, do pass ownership to you.

Comment: And, as jbandes states, you need to read the article on memory management (and probably three or four times over the space of a few weeks, in order to "internalize" it).  Similarly, you may want to seek out the equivalent section in any reference books you have.  The basic concepts are simple, but it takes awhile to get your mind around them.